# python operations on multiple columns after group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like below:

```
df = {'col_1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
      'col_2': [1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1],
      'col_3':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

I want something like:

```
df['col_4'] =  df.groupby(['col_3'])['col_1','col_2'].transform((col_1*col_2)/sum(col_2))
```

which is the the multiplication of `col_1` and `col_2` then divided by sum of `col_2` in each group, defined by `col_3`. The  expected result should be:

```
df
   col_1  col_2 col_3  col_4
0      1      1     A   2.00
1      2      1     A   2.00
2      3      1     A   2.00
3      4      0     A   2.00
4      5      0     A   2.00
5      6      1     B   8.33
6      7      0     B   8.33
7      8      0     B   8.33
8      9      1     B   8.33
9     10      1     B   8.33
```

Anyone know how to get there?

Comment: An expected output would really help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you wish to calculatd the *sum* of `col_1 * col_2` groupwise, you can define a `GroupBy` object and use `transform` + `sum` twice:

```
g = df.eval('prod=col_1*col_2').groupby('col_3')
df['col_4'] = g['prod'].transform('sum') / g['col_2'].transform('sum')

print(df)

   col_1  col_2 col_3     col_4
0      1      1     A  2.000000
1      2      1     A  2.000000
2      3      1     A  2.000000
3      4      0     A  2.000000
4      5      0     A  2.000000
5      6      1     B  8.333333
6      7      0     B  8.333333
7      8      0     B  8.333333
8      9      1     B  8.333333
9     10      1     B  8.333333
```

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick, really new to Python, can you explain a little bit more on the usage of `df.eval'? that's completely new to me.

Comment: @JasonGoal, I can't do much better than the [`pd.eval` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.eval.html), here it's used as an efficient way of evaluating expressions, the default engine is called `'numexpr'` and it bypasses much of the Pandas overhead.